# Outputting content onto rails website from Third Party API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, httparty

I am using the HTTParty Gem to access data from a third party API.

I have set up the model to successfully retrieve/parse the data from the other website.

What I do not know: What code is required in the controller to allow me to display the content in the view (and ultimately the website).

Here is my code for the model file called representatives.rb

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'httparty'

class Representative < ApplicationRecord

include HTTParty
    base_uri 'whoismyrepresentative.com'
    default_params :output => 'json'
    format :json


  def self.find_by_zip(zip)
    get('/getall_mems.php', :query => {:zip => zip})
  end

end

puts Representative.find_by_zip(92651).inspect
```

Here are my Json results:

```
<HTTParty::Response:0x7fa591c4a778 parsed_response={"results"=>[{"name"=>"Dana Rohrabacher", "party"=>"R", "state"=>"CA", "district"=>"48", "phone"=>"202-225-2415", "office"=>"2300 Rayburn House Office Building", "link"=>"http://rohrabacher.house.gov"}, {"name"=>"Darrell Issa", "party"=>"R", "state"=>"CA", "district"=>"49", "phone"=>"202-225-3906", "office"=>"2269 Rayburn House Office Building", "link"=>"http://issa.house.gov"}, {"name"=>"Barbara Boxer", "party"=>"D", "state"=>"CA", "district"=>"Junior Seat", "phone"=>"202-224-3553", "office"=>"112 Hart Senate Office Building", "link"=>"http://www.boxer.senate.gov"}, {"name"=>"Dianne Feinstein", "party"=>"D", "state"=>"CA", "district"=>"Senior Seat", "phone"=>"202-224-3841", "office"=>"331 Hart Senate Office Building", "link"=>"http://www.feinstein.senate.gov"}]}
```

So what do I need to put in the representatives_controller.rb as well as the view files at this point?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

So, you receive a JSON object from the site, and right now you print it, but you want to display it on a rails site?

Probably the easiest way is to receive the data and create an instance of Representative using the data from the JSON object, then pass that object to a Rails template.

You will probably want to use the method #new within the Representative model to create this object, and #show to present it to Rails.

Comment: Would I need to place any code into the controller file before I could see output from the code I place in the view file?

Comment: It's hard for me to answer, I would have organized this differently (not a judgment, just an observation). You need a "new" method to take the results from the HTTP GET and create an instance variable for a representative, then feed that to the view to display.